# How to add folder

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, I have a script of code. When I run it in Module 19 I get "Run-Time Error 76" "Path not Found" . But in my Module 18 the codes runs fine but it elates to different cells.

```
Sub Customer_Save()
    ' 302

    Dim Tmp         As String
    Dim FldName     As String
    
    ' 1. Create the name you want to search for before starting the search
    ' 2. don't refer to cells by their range names (too cumbersome)
    FldName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CUSTOMER INFO").Cells(3, 1).Text                          ' actually, it's Cells(3, 1)
    Debug.Print FldName                                     ' check the name
    If Len(FldName) Then
        Tmp = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CUSTOMER INFO").Cells(3, 7).Text
        If Len(Tmp) Then
            FldName = Tmp & "\" & FldName                   ' observe how to add the path separator
            Debug.Print FldName                             ' check the name
            FldName = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\CUSTOMER HISTORY\" & FldName
            Debug.Print FldName                                 ' check the name
            
            If Dir(FldName) = vbNullString Then MkDir FldName
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell G3 is blank"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Cell A3 is blank"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You should try qualifying your `Cells` references with the sheet they are on, so it does not assume `ActiveSheet`

Comment: That did not work. I still receive the same error.

Comment: If you do `MkDir "C:\Test1\Test2"` it will fail with the mentioned error occurring, if `C:\Test1` does not exist. So you have to do `MkDir "C:\Test1"` first. In your case maybe the folders `CUSTOMER HISTORY` or `Tmp` do not exist.